# SSH log login attempt details

Tags: ssh, login, log, sshd

I my office we are using Ubuntu Server 12.04. I have installed SSH server in it for clients to access through PuTTY.

Now I need to track the users login details like IP address, hostname and date of login.

Is that possible to trace those information, and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `last` command to view previous logins - this:

```
last -adw
```

will generate lines like this:

```
USERNAME  pts/0        Wed Jan 29 10:18   still logged in    192.168.1.?
USERNAME  pts/0        Wed Jan 29 10:06 - 10:07  (00:00)     192.168.1.?
```

Where, `USERNAME`, access point, date and time, and IP addresses are displayed. This should work as long as whoever logged in did not wipe these logs:

```
/var/log/wtmp
/var/log/btmp
```

But they would need the root password to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you should already have all those information in the `sshd` log file or even in `/var/log/syslog` file.
What you can try to see what kind of log are generated by `sshd` find the log use by it reading the config file in `/etc/ssh/sshd.conf` (not sure of file name) once you find which file populate by the daemon.
Use the command `tail -f /path/to/log/file` 
and attempt a logging you should see lots of info about login attempt.